# Как расширить виджет Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет. Подскажите плез как решить данную задачку и можно ли это вообще сделать на C++?
Немного вступления.

Работаю в Qt.
Он имеет класс **QWidget** от которого наследуются всякие **QLineEdit**, **QCheckBox**, **QTextEdit** и т.д. (всякие графические элементы). Так же имеется **QTableWidget** в ячейки которого можно пихать разные виджеты (те же **QLineEdit**, **QCheckBox**, **QTextEdit** и т.д.) методом `void setCellWidget(int row, int column, QWidget *widget);`, а получать виджеты можно методом `QWidget *cellWidget(int row, int column) const;`

Так вот, мне нужно как то добавить в **QWidget** пару виртуальных методов, так что бы они были доступны в тех же **QLineEdit**, **QCheckBox**, **QTextEdit** и прочих классах которые наследуются от **QWidget**. Возможно между **QWidget** и его потомками можно создать некую прослойку куда затолкать нужные методы, но я не знаю как. Идея в том что у меня должна быть возможность помещать расширенные виджеты разных типов (**QLineEdit**, **QCheckBox** ...) в **QTableWidget** и потом получать их обратно таким образом, что бы я мог вызывать добавленные мною методы. Но я не могу это делать так как `QTableWidget::cellWidget(row, column);` возвращает указатель на **QWidget** который конечно не имеет моих методов.

Как вариант, можно наследоваться от каждого необходимого графического элемента (**QLineEdit**, **QCheckBox** ...) и писать нужные мне методы в каждом из них.

```
class ExtLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
public:
   void method1();
   void method2();
   ...
}

class ExtCheckBox : public QCheckBox
{
public:
   void method1();
   void method2();
   ...
}

...

tableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 0, new ExtLineEdit);
tableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 1, new ExtCheckBox);
```

Но тут проблема в том что когда я получу данные виджеты из **QTableWidget** в формате указателя на **QWidget** я должен буду знать во что преобразовывать его (в ExtLineEdit, ExtCheckBox или во что-то еще). Этого я не могу знать. Было бы удобно если бы был некий интерфейс к которому можно было бы преобразовать полученный указатель на **QWidget**. И потом все как завещал полиморфизм.

Может я туплю, но у меня никак не получается это реализовать. Помогите плез.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианта решения два:

1. Сделать класс, реализующий необходимые расширения для виджетов (назовем его для примера `Extension`), далее отнаследовать `ExtLineEdit` от `QLineEdit` и `Extension`, `ExtCheckBox` от `QCheckBox` и `Extension` и так далее. Дальше как обычно - получаем указатель на виджет в ячейке, кастуем его к `Extension *` и дергаем методы расширения. Обратите внимание, что не надо наследовать сам класс `Extension` от `QObject`.
2. В том случае если вам надо просто положить определенные данные в объект и потом достать оттуда, и никакой сложной логики не требуется, можно не делать двойного наследования и воспользоваться системой свойств класса `QObject`:

```
    widget->setProperty("answer", 42);
    int answer = widget->property("answer").toInt();
```

Подробнее про свойства тут https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#reading-and-writing-properties-with-the-meta-object-system

Comment: А чем кастовать не подскажите? Просто `QTableWidget::cellWidget` возвращает `QWidget*`, а преобразовать предстоит в Extension. Как я сказал я много чего попробовал и если получается что-то куда то преобразовать, то сам элемент отрисовывается в QTableWidget не так как надо. Например на отображает текст заданный в QLineEdit части класса ExtLineEdit.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<Extension *>(widget());`

Comment: АААА это работает. Громадное спасибо. А то я уже замучился думать как это сделать. Ничего не получалось.